# Replacing List values sequentially with values from another list

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have a list:

```
my_list = ["A", "B", "C", "X", "X", "X"]
```

and I want to replace the X values with values from another list or in my case a 2D list(This list is generated with the repeat number being equal to the number of "X" in the list):

```
combinations = list(itertools.product('LE', repeat= 3))
```

so

```
combinations = [('L', 'L', 'L'), ('L', 'L', 'E'), ('L', 'E', 'L'), ('L', 'E', 'E'), ('E', 'L', 'L'), ('E', 'L', 'E'), ('E', 'E', 'L'), ('E', 'E', 'E')]
```

My question is how do I replace the "X" values in `my_list` with the values from combinations, such that the first result would be `["A", "B", "C", "L", "L", "L"]` and the second result `["A", "B", "C", "L", "L", "E"]` etc. Preferably I would like to put these into a 2D list which I could then print.

Edit: To clarify, `my_list` will be unknown and the "X" values may dispersed in an unknown fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might use:

```
def mergefill(to_fill, fill_char, fill_from):
    for filler in fill_from:
        it = iter(filler)
        yield [c if c != fill_char else next(it) for c in to_fill]
```

which gives

```
>>> my_list = ["A", "B", "C", "X", "X", "X"]
>>> list(mergefill(my_list, 'X', product('LE', repeat=3)))
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'L', 'L', 'L'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'L', 'L', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'L', 'E', 'L'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'L', 'E', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'L', 'L'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'L', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'L'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E']]
```

It also handles cases where the fill characters aren't contiguous:

```
>>> my_list = ["A", "X", "B", "X"]
>>> list(mergefill(my_list, 'X', product('LE', repeat=2)))
[['A', 'L', 'B', 'L'], ['A', 'L', 'B', 'E'], ['A', 'E', 'B', 'L'], ['A', 'E', 'B', 'E']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'X', 'X', 'X']
new_list = [my_list[:3] + list(c) for c in itertools.product('LE',repeat=3)]
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'L', 'L', 'L'],                                                
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'L', 'L', 'E'],                                                
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'L', 'E', 'L'],                                                
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'L', 'E', 'E'],                                                
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'L', 'L'],                                                
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'L', 'E'],                                                
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'L'],                                                
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E']]
```

To get the number of 'X' in my_list:

```
count = len(filter(lambda v: v == 'X',my_list))
```